Is continuous backup of S3 bucket-wise, file-wise or byte-wise?
Assume I have an S3 bucket with continuous backup enabled. There are some files in the bucket that are heavily updated.
How does AWS Backup do the continuous backup?

Is it bucket-wise? For every change per file, we have a copy of the entire bucket?
Is it file-wise? For every change per file, we have a new copy of the entire file?
Is it byte-wise? For every change per file, we just store the updates of the individual bytes?

Personally, since there are many small changes per file and the files can by quite considerable in size, I would prefer to do something like the byte-wise solution.

S3 only allows creation of objects, or replacement of them in whole.  There is no mechanism to modify or change some number of bytes of an existing object.  The docs on S3 backups note "subsequent backups are incremental at object-level", meaning any backup will return you to a place in time for how the objects appeared in the bucket at that time.

@AnonCoward So, if our file is of size 1 GB, and we change one day 10 bytes, and another day some furhter 10 bytes,  would we store 3 GB or only 1 GB + 20 bytes (disregarding some further storage that might be necessary). Which one is correct? Furthermore, is there some documentation for it, such that I can have a look at it?

In that scenario, you will have created three 1 GB objects in a version controlled bucket, for a total of 3 GB.  You can read the backup documentation I linked to, or more generally, the S3 documentation.

To "change 10 bytes" you must first download the file in its entirety, make the change, then re-upload in its entirety. Depending on where you do this (EC2 instance versus on-prem computer), you may pay data transfer charges to download the file. Depending on whether or not you have versioning enabled, you may pay storage chages for the obsolte versions.

For information about how you access S3 objects, read this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Welcome.html#ConsistencyModel (in particular, the part about writes being atomic). NB: there are Linux filesystems (eg, s3fs) that use S3 as a backing store, and appear to allow changes to part of a file. However, they work by downloading and then re-uploading the entire file.
